# Javascript parsing Url

Tags: javascript, parsing, url

I have a Url which is like this.
https://testOne.abcd.com/myOrders/OrderList/Order123.aspx

How do I get only Order123 ?
I used window.location.href.split('/')[5].split('/')[1]

how do i set it dynamically?

TIA

Comment: Do you want to get or set the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use `substr` string method..

```
var filename = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1) // -> 'Order123.aspx'
var filename_noext = filename.substr(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.')) // -> 'Order123'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the file name, minus the extension, this will work.

```
var regex = /.*\/([^\/]+)\.aspx/;

var url = 'https://testOne.abcd.com/myOrders/OrderList/Order123.aspx'

var match = regex.exec(url);
var fileName = match[1];
alert(fileName);   // This will output "Order123"
```